# How to reset an iOS app, using UIAutomation instrument, if the app does not have sign out option

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I want to test the sign in screen and once I complete one test, my app is signed in but for the next test I want to sign out and go to the first screen again. (**PS: App does not have a sign out**).

Is there any way out that I can clear application data without uninstalling the app so that I can resume my tests from the first screen without any break.
Or please suggest if there is any other option.

Comment: "clear application data without killing the data" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAutomation bringing iOS app to a consistent state](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25199922/2063546).

Comment: The best way is to do a quick implementation of the sign out flow in your code and add a small or hidden button (while running in debug mod) and trigger it with your automation. That way you can always sign out at the end of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could try cmd-shift-hh? then swipe the app up, then you can test the app again

Comment: You can't do this from within a UIAutomation run.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of feature is important, because in the case where the app fails a test (and is therefore in an unknown state), you want a reliable way to return to a known state -- like the first screen.

The bad news is that **Apple doesn't give you this within instruments**.

One way to do to it is to take advantage of the shake gesture -- assuming that you don't need it for other things in your app -- so that in a UIAutomation build, calling `target.shake()` will return you to your first screen.

Another way to do it would be to instrument your code so that you can send a reset signal from the shell as part of your test.  In our framework (called [Illuminator](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator)), we provide an [automation bridge](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/docs/Bridge.md) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

driver.resetApp(); It may work. try this.